# Can I easily stop/start Azure Webjobs without going through the UI or FTP?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

The Azure management interface is abhorrently slow to load up the web jobs list, and the new portal just times out and fails 95% of the time.

We have a lot of WebApps (often deployed per region) in Azure running web jobs. It's *extremely* cumbersome and slow to have to go through the UI to do all this.

I know that the Kudu API offers start/stop mechanisms for web jobs and you can just drop a file called 'disable.job' in the job folder to stop it, but these all require going through the extremely annoyingly slow UI to download publish credentials ($username, password).

Is there a PowerShell cmdlet I've somehow missed or a public script out there to help do this? Ideally I just want to supply my Azure credentials or import the certificates.

Comment: While I agree that the situation with the portals is really bad, and the new portal is terribly slow. It isn't at all UI dependent, as all functions are available via rest with Powershell cmdlets following not far behind, there are sometimes odd quirks to how it all works, but I only really venture into the portal when I'm playing with some new aspect of

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's hard to find, but here's a link to the documentation for Start and Stop:

**Start:** 
[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure/start-azurewebsitejob?view=azuresmps-4.0.0)

Example: `Start-AzureWebsiteJob -Name MyWebsite -JobName MyWebJob -JobType Continuous`

**Stop:**
[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure/stop-azurewebsitejob?view=azuresmps-4.0.0)

Example: `Stop-AzureWebsiteJob -Name MyWebsite -JobName MyWebJob`

Answer (score 5):

Al Muhandis,

Actually there is a Rest API that allows to pilot your web jobs.

It allows to list jobs, get a job detail, delete or upoad a job, and some few more,..

Have a look at : 
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API

Regards

Comment: The Kudu REST API, from what I can tell, requires  the website deployment credentials. Just getting these credentials is a massive pain, as it needs to be done manually (I haven't been able to find any automatic ways of getting them).

Comment: `Invoke-AzureResourceAction -ResourceGroupName <resourceGroupName> -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName <siteName>/publishingcredentials -Action list -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force`

Answer (score 1):

Open your resource, web job at https://resources.azure.com. Should be something like `https://resources.azure.com/subscriptions/<your subscription>/resourceGroups/<your group>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<your site name>/continuouswebjobs/<your job name>` and open Powershell tab. There should be up to date samples on how to start / stop a WebJob:

```
# Action start
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName <your groupname> `
       -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/continuouswebjobs `
       -ResourceName <your site name>/<your job> `
       -Action start  -ApiVersion 2018-02-01 -Force
```

Comment: I was blind and now I can see!