# Start Webjob using powershell

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

Scenario:
I have a Azure app service with 2 slots and once I deploy to the staging slot and swap the slots, I would like the webjob on the productions slot to be in running state and the staging slot to be stopped.

Is there a PowerShell way of starting and stopping azure web jobs?

Comment: Found a similar question which was able to resolve the issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128432/can-i-easily-stop-start-azure-webjobs-without-going-through-the-ui-or-ftp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I easily stop/start Azure Webjobs without going through the UI or FTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128432/can-i-easily-stop-start-azure-webjobs-without-going-through-the-ui-or-ftp)