# StorageAccountAlreadyTaken error at incremental deployment

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell

This template run on the same resource group produced the error `StorageAccountAlreadyTaken` but it is expected to do incremental deployment, ie. not to create any new resources. How to fix this?

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
  "name": "[variables('prodSaName')]",
  "tags": { "displayName": "Storage account" },
  "apiVersion": "2016-01-01",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "sku": { "name": "Standard_LRS" },
  "kind": "Storage",
  "properties": {}
},
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
  "name": "[ge.saName(parameters('brn'), parameters('environments')[copyIndex()])]",
  "tags": { "displayName": "Storage account" },
  "apiVersion": "2016-01-01",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "sku": { "name": "Standard_LRS" },
  "kind": "Storage",
  "copy": {
    "name": "EnvStorageAccounts",
    "count": "[length(parameters('environments'))]"
  },
```

Run `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment @args -debug` with this template and it outputs:

```bsh
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 15:03:38 - Error: Code=StorageAccountAlreadyTaken; Message=The storage account named
UNIQUENAMEOFTHERESOURCE is already taken.
At C:\coding\gameo\gameoemergency\provision.run.ps1:101 char:9
+         New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment @args -debug
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdle
   t
```

PS. Somehow running from VSTS doesn't have this result. That run from local machine. Also there is no such error in Activity Log, strangely.

Update.

If I don't do these selects of a subscription as below but only for RM there are no errors.

```bsh
    Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionID $Cfg.subscriptionId > $null

    # this seems to be the reason of the error, if removed - works:
    Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId $Cfg.subscriptionId > $null

    # ... in order to run:
    exec { Start-AzureWebsiteJob @startArgs | out-null }
```

Comment: I don't understand, does it error when you use the Select-AzureRmSubscription or when you use the Select-AzureSubscription?

Comment: @PhilPeters The later one

Comment: So the `Select-AzureSubscription` would log you in to a non Resource Manager subscription and therefore you cannot deploy Azure Resource Manager (ARM) templates there afaik. [This article says more about](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-deployment-model#migrate-from-classic-to-resource-manager) Classic V ARM deployment option

Comment: @PhilPeters Yeah, smth like this. Time and again I find answers at https://resources.azure.com. Answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128432/can-i-easily-stop-start-azure-webjobs-without-going-through-the-ui-or-ftp

Comment: If your issue has been solved, you could add an answer and mark it for others to refer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its a help but I had this issue with APIs prior to 2016-01-01 as there was a [known bug](https://geeks.ms/davidjrh/2016/07/06/the-storage-account-already-exists-error-when-redeploying-an-arm-template-2/). I updated to 2016-12-01 as this was the latest at the time and it worked for me.

Have you tried updating the api to the latest and trying again? The latest is  [2018-02-01](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storage/storageaccounts)

Comment: Yes, I tried it. Does not work. See the above update. Turns out to be issue with old and the new ways (RM)..

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of selecting a subscription twice for Resource Manager cmdlets and using `Select-AzureSubscription` as below:

```bsh
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionID $Cfg.subscriptionId > $null

# this seems to be the reason of the error, if removed - works:
# Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId $Cfg.subscriptionId > $null
```

To avoid old cmdlets (before RM) we can use `Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction`. See example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51712321/511144

Answer (score 0):

A good thing to do before performing a deployment is to validate the resources that if it can be created with the name provided. For EventHub and Storage Account there are built in cmdlets that allows you to check it.

## For EventHub

```
Test-AzureRmEventHubName -Namespace $eventHubNamespaceName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NameAvailable
        if ($availability -eq $true) {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green `r`n"Entered Event Hub Namespace name is available"
```

## For Storage Account

```
 while ($true) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow `r`n"Enter Storage account name (Press Enter for default) : " -NoNewline
        $storageAccountName = Read-Host
        if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($storageAccountName)) {
            $storageAccountName = $defaultstorageAccountName
        }
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow `r`n"Checking whether the entered name for Storage account is available"
        $availability = Get-AzureRmStorageAccountNameAvailability -Name $storageAccountName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NameAvailable
        if ($availability -eq $true ) {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green `r`n"Entered Storage account name is available"
            break
        }
        Write-Host `r`n"Enter valid Storage account name"
    }
```

This will prevent deployment errors by validating before deployment and asking the user to enter a valid name again if the entered one is not present.